# Getting the JavaScript inside the codebehind to return true or false?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm having an issue with calling a JavaScript function while in the codebehind method:

This code populates the textboxes with the cookieValues data.  The JavaScript CalculateDOBAge gets called and does an existing DOB calculation and determines if the Age being returned is the same age as the DOB being returned.

However, if it determines that the DOB calculates a different Age then what is being returned I want to clear out the txtDOB and txtMonths textboxes.  This is the part that isn't working.

**ASP.Net Code Behind:**

```c#
private void LoadSheetValues()
{
    txtDOB.Text = cookieValues["DOB"];
    txtAge.Text = cookieValues["Age"];
    txtMonths.Text = cookieValues["Months"];

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "CalculateDOBAge", "calcDOBAge()", true);

}
```

**JavaScript snippet:**

```js
    if ((displayYear == age) && (displayMonth == months)) {
        //The SAME

    } else {
        //Different
        document.getElementById("txtDOB").value = '';
        document.getElementById("txtMonths").value = '';
    }
```

The javascript code is called from the `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` call and I can step through the values being blanked out.  However, I think I dealing with a page lifecycle issue as when I check the screen after completion, the values remain in the textboxes.

I need the `RegisterStartupScript` (vs `RegisterClientScriptBlock`) as the CalculateDOBAge function needs the elements to be available and populated (so I can do the DOB calculation).

Is there a way to set this up using the RegisterStartupScript to return a True/False and then I can continue in the codebehind to clear out the textbox text?

Unfortunately this is an ancient application and jQuery or any modern frameworks are not available.

**Full JavaScript:**

```
function DOBAgeMonthCheck(birthDate, dateFormat) {
    try {
        if (dateFormat == 'MMDD') {
            var bmo = birthDate.substr(0, 2);
            var bday = birthDate.substr(3, 2);
            var byr = birthDate.substr(6, 4);
        } else if (dateFormat == 'DDMM') {
            var bmo = birthDate.substr(3, 2);
            var bday = birthDate.substr(0, 2);
            var byr = birthDate.substr(6, 4);
        } else if (dateFormat == 'YMD') {
            var byr = birthDate.substr(0, 4);
            var bmo = birthDate.substr(5, 2);
            var bday = birthDate.substr(8, 2);
        }

        //replaces *ALL* "_" with ""
        byr = byr.replace(/_/g, "");
        bmo = bmo.replace(/_/g, "");
        bday = bday.replace(/_/g, "");

        var yrDiff;
        var displayMonth;
        var displayYear;

        var now = new Date();

        tday = now.getDate();
        tmo = now.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
        tyr = now.getFullYear();

        //set four digit year
        var tmpYr = tyr.toString();
        byr = removeLeadingZero(byr);
        var tmpLength = byr.length;
        if (tmpLength < 4) {
            if (byr > tmpYr.substr(2, 2))
                byr = "1900".substr(0, 4 - tmpLength) + byr;
            else
                byr = "2000".substr(0, 4 - tmpLength) + byr;
        }

        if ((tmo > bmo) || (tmo == bmo & tday >= bday))
            yrDiff = parseInt(byr)
        else
            yrDiff = parseInt(byr) + 1

        if (tyr - yrDiff < 0)
            displayYear = 0;
        else
            displayYear = (tyr - yrDiff);

        if (tmo >= bmo)
            displayMonth = tmo - parseInt(bmo);
        else
            displayMonth = 12 - (parseInt(bmo) - tmo);

        var age;
        var months;

        try { age = document.getElementById("txtAge").value; } catch (err) { }

        try { months = document.getElementById("txtMonths").value; } catch (err) { }

        if ((displayYear == age) && (displayMonth == months)) {
            //The SAME

        } else {
            //Different
            document.getElementById("txtDOB").value = '';
            document.getElementById("txtMonths").value = '';
        }
    }
    catch (err) { }
    }
```

I'm getting to the `//Different` section and watching the values being cleared.

Comment: When are you assigning your script in code behind? It needs to be created before Page_Load.

Comment: so I can't call a specific function like this inside the codebehind method?  It appears to call it just fine like this...

Comment: Yes you can, but move your ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript call to page PreRender. That way the script is rendered before values are bound to controls. As what I've understood, this should fix your problem.

Comment: @JanneP - Do I put my ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "CalculateDOBAge", "calcDOBAge()", true); in the PreRender - just like I have it?  I don't really want it to run all the time.  I just want it to run after a specific method is run.

Comment: Is that specific method an event? What I've done is I have checked the PostBack control in code behind and add the script based on that control value.

Comment: Does `calcDOBAge()` fire when `LoadSheetValues()` is called? If so the problem may be in the (incomplete) javascript snippet. Post the full snippet.

Comment: @VDWWD - Yes that is only when it is called.  And I updated the full function.  As I noted in the question - I am witnessing the values being cleared.

Comment: Client script cannot interact with the server code. RegisterStartupScript does exactly what it says; it registers a script which will be run when the page starts. It doesn't make sense for it to return a value, because it's not running the script itself.

Comment: @webdad3 maybe I'm wrong _hence, the comment_, but you can send the value "true or false" in a HiddenField and read it in server side...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - Yeah, I hear what you are saying and I am witnessing that.  Do you know why then the values aren't being blanked out?  Is it some page lifecycle issue?

Comment: @Mauricio - Yes you are correct on that, however, I was hoping to have it go from ServerSide to ClientSide and back to ServerSide synchronously.